# Does Scala provide an easy way to convert Infix expressions to postfix ones?

Tags: scala, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I a beginner in Scala and I am writing a program in Scala to convert infix arithmetic expression to the postfix one meanwhile wondering whether Scala provided an easier way to handle these kind of conversions.
Can anyone guide me if there is any easier way for it?

Comment: arithmetic expressions such as ((1+2)*5)/12 and I am parsing them using scala parser

Comment: here is something for getting idea about scala parser : http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html that parser is not a problem it's working and checking my syntax correctly, now I have an infix arithmetic operation that I want to convert it to postfix and wondering if Scala made an easy way to do that

Comment: So by "scala parser" you mean the scala parser combinator library? And "expressions" refers to expressions in the language you're parsing, not scala expressions?

Comment: yes it's just simple arithmetic expression like ((1+2)*5)/12 it has been parsed for the syntax checking no I want to change this infix to postfix

Comment: What is the representation you are parsing to? If the parser builds a tree of this expression (something like Div(Mul(Add(1, 2), 5), 12)) it's as easy as the post-order traversal of this tree: first recursively print the left operand, than the right operand and then the operation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order CItation: `It [Post-order traversal] can also generate a postfix representation of a binary tree.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it is to use Dijkstra's [Shunting Yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm. [Here](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/07/02/shuntingyard-algorithm-in-scala/) is one implementation in Scala.